# How to loop through PHP Class with Function variable inside

Tags: php, wordpress

Goal: My goals is to create a function that executes multiple times and adds ascript to the footer of the page.

This works, but now I want it to work with variables. How do I put them into the second function ($A, $B, $C) and give input to them?
This is my code:

```
class myClass {
    //Put it in the footer
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', array( $this, 'myFunction' ) );
    }


    //myFunction
     public function myFunction($A, $B, $C) {

    echo'<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {


      $("#gallery_'.$A.'").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

          items : '.$B.',
          itemsDesktop : [1199,'.$B.'],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,'.$B.'],
          itemsTablet: [768,'.$C.']

      });

    });
    </script>';

    }
}
```

To run the function I now use:

```
$run = new WP_Docs_Class();
```

I want to have something like:

```
$run = new WP_Docs_Class($A, $B, $C);
or
$run = new WP_Docs_Class(120, 9, 2);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What you are not getting done?

Comment: Please teach yourself the basics of class based object oriented programming. Your lack of this knowledge will hinder you in everything you are about to do.

Comment: Is it working with `$run = new WP_Docs_Class();` as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store them into class variables

```
class myClass {
    private $A, $B, $C;
    //Put it in the footer
    public function __construct($A, $B, $C) {
        $this->A = $A;
        $this->B = $B;
        $this->C = $C;
        add_action( 'genesis_after_footer', array( $this, 'myFunction' ) );
    }


    //myFunction
     public function myFunction() {

    echo'<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {


      $("#gallery_'.$this->A.'").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

          items : '.$this->B.',
          itemsDesktop : [1199,'.$this->B.'],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,'.$this->B.'],
          itemsTablet: [768,'.$this->C.']

      });

    });
    </script>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work if yes may you explain a little?

Comment: The callback passed to `add_action` is a method of a member class, thats why he has to pass `$this` as the object reference over which it will be executed. In that sense, you can access the class member variables

Comment: see Usage for [add action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

In WP we call added actions using [do_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)

```
class myClass{

  //Put it in the footer
  public function __construct(){
    add_action('genesis_after_footer', array(
      $this,
      'myFunction'));
  }

  //myFunction
  public function myFunction($data){

    echo'<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#gallery_' . $data[0] . '").owlCarousel({
          autoPlay: false, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
          items : ' . $data[1] . ',
          itemsDesktop : [1199,' . $data[1] . '],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,' . $data[1] . '],
          itemsTablet: [768,' . $data[2] . ']
      });
    });
    </script>';
  }

}
```

**Calling after this update in class code:**

```
do_action( 'genesis_after_footer', array( $A, $B, $C ) );
```

OR

```
do_action( 'genesis_after_footer', array( 120, 9, 2 ) );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! The solution of Nadir works very good. I also tried to test this one, but I don't understand how to hook into this function multiple times. Does it also work with `$run = new myClass(120, 9, 2);`?